# How to use "frequently" correctly?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I wrote the following sentence, but I think the word "frequently" is not used correctly.

> Turning on and off the machines frequently may damage them.

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you mean to say that frequently doing this has the effect, or do you mean to say that doing this (at all) frequently has the effect?

Comment: I want to say if we turn on and turn off  the machines blow-by-blow (consecutive), then it will be damaged.

Comment: Actually it's normal to "split" the phrasal verb "turn on / turn off"; it sounds very strange not to split it in this case.   I might say "Turning the machines on and off too often may cause damage."   Or you might need a different adverb there, like "rapidly" or "in quick succession", depending on exactly what the real problem is.  Do the machines have to finish their power-up cycle and run for a few minutes in order to power down safely?  Is the power-up process an "expensive" thing that causes wear and tear so it's better to leave the machine running instead of turning it off?

Comment: The second one is correct. the power-up process is an expensive thing that causes wear and tear so it's better to leave the machine running instead of turning it off.

Answer (score 1):

#### "The machines are damaged by..."

Looking at:

> Turning on and off the machines frequently may damage them.

... I don't see a grammatical problem with "frequently", but the sentence is slightly ambiguous. If you read the words aloud with different timing, you'll get two different meanings.

1. Turning on and off the machines // frequently may damage them.
2. Turning on and off the machines frequently // may damage them.

### Put the adverb near the verb

Assuming that Number 2 is what you want to convey, my personal choice would be to move the adverb "frequently" up to the head of the sentence so that it's closer to the verb that it modifies ("to turn on (and off)").

- **Frequently** turning on and off the machines may damage them.

### Better: Remove the ambiguity

However, I'd use the word "repeatedly" in this warning rather than "frequently", as it clearly can only apply to "turning on and off" and not "may damage":

- **Repeatedly** turning on and off the machines may damage them.

Answer (score -1):

'Frequently' is a frequency adverb. Its place accepted by grammar rules is before the  main verb. So you must put it after the modal 'may' in your sentence.

Comment: If you move it there, you change the meaning of the sentence.  In its original position, it means "doing this a lot might cause damage".  When you move it, it means "doing this will cause damage a lot of the time."